High swap consumption during database backup with mariabackup
We are experiencing a swap consumption problem when backing up our database.
Every evening at 01am we run the mariabackup command and during the process swap usage rises sharply until it reaches 100% and only drops back to normal usage around 10am at best.
The VM has an Alamalinux 8.4 OS, around 60GB RAM and a 4GB SWAP partition.
Normal” resource utilization (excluding backup) is around 70-80% of RAM and 70-80% of SWAP.
The vm.swapiness value has been set to 0, but this does not change the SWAP consumption. RAM usage remains fairly stable outside or during evening backups.

Do you have any idea why SWAP is used so much during backups?
Is this normal? Do you have any recommendations?

As not a programming question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/ maybe.

Thank you danblack, i have posted a question there

Cross ref link unix cross posted

So from graphs it looks like about 28% swap increase which on 4G is 1.12GB. MariaDB-backup uses its own Innodb buffer pool (changeable with --use-memory=) to keep track of data and changes when running --prepare. 1G is the default for this.
For the backup, I see that no extra RAM is used, oddly it drops slightly, so it seems to be used on swap. It had to go somewhere.
Could the slight drop in percentage of 60G correspond to the larger percentage increase of a 4G swap if you look in absolute terms.
The main metric for swap health is however that the amount of swap-in/swap-out remains low more than the actual amount used. smem can show swap usage per process to confirm it is backup and what's used all the way to 10am. Even if its part of mariadbd that is swapped out, it obviously isn't a significant use (unless there's lots of swap in/out going on).
Note: I'm not sure this is a complete answer

after checking, it seems that the swap overconsumption is caused by the tar command issued after the mariabackup to archive the command result.
Is there any way of obtaining a tar file directly from the mariabackup command?
For your information:

the mariabackup command takes about 5 min, while the tar command takes about 1 hour.

the possibility of increasing the swap to 8GB should be tested.

in our context, deleting the swap partition is not possible for administrative reasons.



Is this actually impacting on the workload? You can do things with mbstream to process the backup elsewhere.
